# Not charging iPhone when using GPS apps

Tags: iphone, gps, charger

I have GPS Drive App [Motion X-GPS](http://news.motionx.com/category/motionx-gps-drive/). I tried to use this app with my iPhone/iPad cigarette charger plugged in, but the battery is keep draining even with the charger to make this app almost useless for long distance driving. I used the charger without any problem with other apps.

Why iPhone is not charging with GPS apps? Is this iPhone's known issue? Is this an issue with Motion X-GPS? Or new/better cigarette charger is needed to solve this issue?

I use [Scosche](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003N7NO4Q) that has 2.1A port, but it doesn't charge when I use this port with iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's just because the GPS app is using much more power then the charger can deliver. You should check the amp. of your charger. I have one of 2100 mA and I can use my iPad with Navigon while my iPad is charging.

[This](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H7018ZM/A/incase-mini-car-charger) charger sold in the Apple Store will provide your iPhone enough power to both run the GPS app and charge at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Michiel: I tested with a charger delivers 2100mA for iPad, but it doesn't work with my iPhone. I guess iPhone doesn't suck in 2100mA to run GPS app. I elaborated my post.

Comment: My charger (2100mA) is capable of charging both my iPad and my iPhone, so an iPhone sure is capable of "sucking" up the 2100mA

Comment: My car charger can drive an iPhone 4S running Navigon while the battery is still (slowly) charging. And I know it uses a lot of power because the iPhone can get very hot when Navigon is running. However, with the same Navigon on iPad 2 connected to the same charger, the iPad loses 2-5% of charge per hour (probably due to more current being devoted to powering the bigger screen). So indeed, it seems to me that the submitter just needs to get a decent car charger.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a (possibly unavoidable) problem with that particular type of GPS app on that particular device model.

An app using lots of graphics GPU features at high display frame rates in addition to continuous access to the GPS radio plus with the cellular radio power turned up in weak cell signal areas might consume more current than the battery charge circuit is capable of replenishing on some device.  e.g. even with a 10+ watt USB charger, the iPhone (operation plus charging) circuitry may only be able to use 5 watts total to avoid overheating.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong if your high amp charger doesn't work with any device (and with your device in particular).

Yes - it's well known that some GPS apps can use more power than a charger can provide - drawing down the battery over time. I have seen the battery drain about 10% to 20% capacity an hour when everything is operating properly.

If your drain is higher than that, then perhaps the phone needs to be restored or there is some problem with the charger. Have you sent the developer a support request to see if you can use a setting to slow down the CPU if it turns out to be a software issue?

Basically, it depends on how much a deficit your device is running to know what to blame in your instance, but you could test things by enabling the detailed charge indication and testing how long it takes to go from full to 75% charge. Both in the car and in your house connected to the Apple AC adapter.

If the car charger isn't keeping up with the wall adapter, then you can replace that. If it's draining equally at home, then it's either the device or the software.